# Pull last datetime from table 2 that occured before datetime being pulled in table 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Trying to pull what function an associate was badged into prior to the actions i am pulling. Do not have my work computer so this is not the exact query just references for what i am trying to accomplish.

```
;
drop table if exists #il
drop table if exists #ts
drop table if exists #il2
;
select 
il.[user],
il.[location],
il.[action],
il.[timestamp]
into #il
from inventorylogs as il (nolock)
where il.[action] in ('ActionType1','ActionType2')
---
select 
ts.[employeeid],
ts.[in],
ts.[department]
into #ts
from timestation as ts (nolock)

---
select 
il.[user],
il.[location],
il.[action],
[lasttime] = last_value(ts.[in]) over (partition by il.[timestamp] order by il.[user] rows unbounded preceding,
[lastdepartment] = last_value(ts.[department]) over (partition by il.[timestamp] order by il.[user] rows unbounded preceding
into #il2
from #il as il(nolock)
inner join #ts as ts(nolock) on il.user = ts.employeeid
--

[TotalMeasureableActions] = sum(il.[location]),
il.[user]
from #il2 as il (nolock)
where il.[lastdepartment] = 'SpecificFunction'
group by 
il.[user]
```

`ts.[in]` is the time they badged into various function. Want this to return the last`ts.[in]`along with the associated `ts.[department] that occurred before each il.[timestamp]`.

the end goal of this entire query is to to `sum(il.[location]) where last(ts.[in]), last(ts.[department] = 'Specific Department' group by il.[user]`

The challenge being the badge into multiple functions throughout a day and what i have tried either only returns their very function / badge in or not the correct one

| User | location | action | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User1 | ShelfLocation1 | Pick | 12/10/2020 07:55:07 |

| department | in |
| --- | --- |
| Function1 | 12/10/2020 07:15:07 |
| Function2 | 12/10/2020 07:45:07 |
| Function3 | 12/10/2020 08:45:07 |
| Function4 | 12/10/2020 09:15:07 |

Temp table il2 expected result

| User | location | action | timestamp | department | in |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User1 | ShelfLocation1 | Pick | 12/10/2020 07:55:07 | Function2 | 12/10/2020 07:45:07 |

| user | TotalMeasureableactions |
| --- | --- |
| User1 | 10 |
| User2 | 34 |
| User3 | 34 |
| User4 | 45 |

If there is an easier way to do this and i am over-complicating this; I am all for it and open to suggestions.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected output. You have used `il.datetime`  but it really exists in il? at least not in the question.

Comment: @Popeye Whoops meant to put il.timestamp there, fixed that above as well as added some sample data and expected output. Brand new to this site so let me know if there is a better way to format the above. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I find your question very hard to follow.  But based on this:

> Want this to return the lastts.[in]along with the associated ts.[department] that occurred before each il.[timestamp].

You can use `apply`:

```
select il.*, ts.*
from il outer apply
     (select top (1) ts.*
      from ts
      where il.user = ts.employeeid and
            t2.[in] < il.timestamp
      order by t2.[in] desc
     ) ts;
```

The question would be easier to follow if structured as:

1. "I am trying to do X".
2. "The data looks like Y".
3. "I have tried Z".